# JAX-WS AXIS2 webservice on WEBSPHERE 6.1 deployment gives  java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: jax-ws, apache-axis, websphere-6.1

I'm trying to deploy a web service based on jax ws axis2 on websphere 6.1. It works properly in tomcat 5.5

I've been following the steps described in the **axis2** online documentation available at this link

[Avoiding conflicts with WebSphere's JAX-WS runtime](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/app_server.html)

THe service seems to deploy properly (no message errors in System out) and the return the wsdl file when requested. I'm also able to engage a module on web service for logging purposes.

The problem comes out when invoking the service from a client: it returns a WebFault

*Stacktrace on the server is as follow*

> [10/02/12 16.58.59:861 CET] 0000001e FactoryRegist E
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.registry.FactoryRegistry  null
>                                    java.lang.VerifyError    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:224)
>     at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:194)    at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:61)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:127)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.(ModelBuilder.java:152)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:87)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:422)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.(JAXBContextImpl.java:286)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:139)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:117)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)     at
>   javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:214)  at
>   javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:375)     at
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)  at
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)  at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.addressing.factory.impl.JAXWSEndpointReferenceFactoryImpl$1.run(JAXWSEndpointReferenceFactoryImpl.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:132)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.addressing.factory.impl.JAXWSEndpointReferenceFactoryImpl.(JAXWSEndpointReferenceFactoryImpl.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.registry.FactoryRegistry.init(FactoryRegistry.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.registry.FactoryRegistry.(FactoryRegistry.java:97)
>     at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:194)    at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.util.MessageUtils.getMessageFromMessageContext(MessageUtils.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.MessageContext.(MessageContext.java:120)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver.receive(JAXWSMessageReceiver.java:124)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
>     at wgs.v3.servlet.JetAxisServlet.doPost(JetAxisServlet.java:30)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1096)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:570)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3444)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:267)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:815)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1466)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:119)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:267)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:195)   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:743)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:873)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)

Working on this problem and looking around the source code of the libaries it comes out that the error occurs in JAXBContext newIstance method

enabling the trace log on class loader is shown as the javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConstants class is loaded from PARENT because it's not found in the WAR module and this gives the java.lang.VerifyError

I'm not able to find a solution

Comment: After working on the problem it seems that the java.lang.VerifyError
comes out from this code
JAXBContext.newInstance(W3CEndpointReference.class,                                                        SubmissionEndpointReference.class);

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got out from this problem

Just adding in the war lib the following jars

```
xml-apis.jar
xercesImpl.jar
xalan.jar
```

Every thing is correctly found inside the war without conflicts with IBM libaries